# JQuery FlexiGrid - Ajax implementation for one column in a table

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I have a Flexigrid table where i need to make a Ajax call on a column, whose value changes every 10 secs. Please help me on how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the flexReload() method, coupled with a javascript [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function call set to fire every ten seconds.